# Grothendieck universe "completeness"

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

Say universe $U$ is "complete" iff every $U$-small set is a $U$-set.
Does there exist a "complete" universe?

Definitions: A $U$-set is an element of $U$. A $U$-small set is isomorphic (i.e. bijective) to an element of $U$.

I'm reading about category theory and I thought of the above question. The reason is that there seems to be no "real difference" between $U$-small sets and $U$-sets. It seems like any such $U$ would be "too big to be a set," but I don't know how to prove this.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the answer.

If $U$ were "complete," then $\{U\} \in U$, a contradiction.

Comment: This is the correct answer. However, note that if $U$ is a universe, $a\in U$, $f:a\to b$ is a definable function and $b\subset U$, then in fact $b\in U$, by the axiom schema of replacement. This tells you that subsets of $U$ which aren't in $U$ are big